# GemFire Queries gradually slow down after running for few hours

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We are in performance testing of our Spring Boot based application which uses Spring Data GemFire to connect with Pivotal GemFire.

During these tests what we have observed is OQL queries are slowing down gradually with time. We are already monitoring heap memory, cpu, threads, number of queries, transaction counts and connection counts but nowhere can we see the gradual increase. All the parameters are consistent throughout the performance test duration but query performance shows gradual slowness with time. I am not sure apart from the parameters which we are already monitoring what else would cause this slowness and needs to be monitored. Can you please advise ?

Version Details-

- Spring Data GemFire 1.8.10 RELEASE
- Spring Boot - 1.4.6 RELEASE
- Pivotal GemFire - 8.2.13
- Websphere Application Server - 8.5.9

Other details

- Cluster Size : 3 Nodes each with 60 gb heap-size each
- Region Type : I see both replicated and partitioned regions in slow queries
- Indexes used  : Yes
- Overflow Configured : Yes to the disk store
- Persistent Regions : Yes
- Eviction - 80% but heap is below 70 most of the time.
- Indexes on Data set:  Depending on usage, Lowest 1 index and around 6 max. However when we look at the queries in logs always one index is shown as used.

Comment: How large is your data set?  How many nodes in your cluster?  What type of Regions are you using (e.g. PARTITION)? 
Are you using any OQL Indexes?  Could you share pertinent bits (or all) of your (Spring/GemFire) configuration?  Do you have an example/test repo that might isolate/reproduce your problem?  How are you measuring your query performance? Also, do know whether the member is perhaps running low on memory (causing GC pauses)?  Is there anything else happening in the network when the queries slow down?  Is there anything that stands out in the server logs?  Etc?

Comment: Additional questions... are you performing a join (is it possible to share the query)?  Are there any other data access operations occurring on the data when the query is in progress?  Given the data set size, do you have overflow configured? Is your Region or Regions persistent?  Do you have eviction/expiration policies?  Are you using off-heap or compression?  Do you notice any other GemFire activity during this time (e.g. rebalance (particularly in the case of PARTITION Regions), compaction)?  Do you have redundancy configured?  Etc?

Comment: More questions... if you have OQL indexes, is your index maintenance sync or async?  How many indexes do you have on the queried data set? Etc?

Comment: Thanks John. I have enhance my question with more details. We are primarily using replicated regions and we use JTA provided by Websphere.  At present we dont have any repo to reproduce the problems. I am not sure if I would be able to develop anything soon as application is complex in nature. As per the zabbix monitor we have in place, it shows almost 30/40 percent help was free during execution. In some cases we have joins however I can see queries without joins also gradually responding slowly.  Regions are accessed by multiple flows, occasionally there are inserts.

Comment: additionally I am not sure on how to check if gemfire forces rebalance during execution of the tests. do you hany hints/ideas